# Why does Vue.js/Axios don't render the data I defined?

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I query data from a third party API using Vue.js + Axios. The data is returned nicely however it has a bit of confusing structure (nested array).

Somehow the Vue doesn't properly work and I don't see any data renderedat the frontend.

**Important to note:**

The Vue adds exactly 20 html divs to the frontend after I run the code (which matchs the number of containing elements, but it doesn't display the according data(see images below)).

What might be an issue here?

**Javascript part**:

```
var app = new Vue({
    el: '#app_name',
    data: {
      info: []
    },
    mounted() {
      axios
        .get("https://cors-anywhere.herokuapp.com/https://www.api-football.com/demo/api/v2/leagueTable/" + league_id)
        .then(response => {
          this.info = response.data.api.standings[0];
          console.log(response.data.api.standings[0]);
        });
    }
```

**HTML part:**

```
          <div class="table" id="app_name">
            <div><p>Team</p></div>
            <div v-for="Rank in info">

            <p>{{ Rank }}</p>

            </div>
```

**This is the JSON return, note the nested array:**

```
{
    "api": {
        "results": 1,
        "standings": [
            [
                {
                    "rank": 1,
                    "team_id": 85,
                    "teamName": "Paris Saint Germain",
                    "logo": "https://media.api-football.com/teams/85.png",
                    "group": "Ligue 1",
                    "forme": "DLWLL",
                    "description": "Promotion - Champions League (Group Stage)",
                    "all": {
                        "matchsPlayed": 35,
                        "win": 27,
                        "draw": 4,
                        "lose": 4,
                        "goalsFor": 98,
                        "goalsAgainst": 31
                    },
                    "home": {
                        "matchsPlayed": 18,
                        "win": 16,
                        "draw": 2,
                        "lose": 0,
                        "goalsFor": 59,
                        "goalsAgainst": 10
                    },
                    "away": {
                        "matchsPlayed": 17,
                        "win": 11,
                        "draw": 2,
                        "lose": 4,
                        "goalsFor": 39,
                        "goalsAgainst": 21
                    },
                    "goalsDiff": 67,
                    "points": 85,
                    "lastUpdate": "2019-05-04"
                },
                {...}
            ]
        ]
    }
}
```

**Before Javascript is executed:**

[image]

**After Javascript is executed:**

[image]

**UPDATE**

I tried it with this modification (source: https://github.com/axios/axios/issues/738) but still I don't have any data rendered

```
  var app = new Vue({
    el: '#app_name',
    data: {
      info: []
    },
    mounted() {
      axios.interceptors.request.use(config => {
        config.paramsSerializer = params => {
          // Qs is already included in the Axios package
          return Qs.stringify(params, {
            arrayFormat: "brackets",
            encode: false
          });
        };
        return config;
      });
      axios
        .get("https://cors-anywhere.herokuapp.com/https://www.api-football.com/demo/api/v2/leagueTable/" + league_id)
        .then(response => {
          this.info = response.data.api.standings;
          console.log(response.data.api.standings);
        });
    }
```

Comment: Don't make api call in mounted(), try it in created() or even before that, make sure you have all data before mount.

Comment: Tried it, no change. What to insert into mounted then?

Comment: @Phanti `created` hook is ideal for fetching data. Try putting a `v-if` on the iterating `<div v-for="(Rank, index) in info" :key="index">`. Also this `{{Rank}}` would be the whole object, what do want to access from that?.

Comment: I have eleven objects I want to fetch, but if one would work I could work out the others. I tried your code and still I get empty html containers without any rendered data. The Vue just creates the containers. The issue is how to refer to the elements in the array since it is nested somehow..

Comment: That API could take so long time to finish, and by the time, the created() and mounted() already run. Make `v-if="info.length"`, if it 0, show the loading, if it has length, show the loop. Also, try not to assign into array, Vue can not detect the change of array if you assign new value to it. Use push or something else.

https://vuejs.org/v2/guide/list.html#Array-Change-Detection

Comment: I tried running this code myself and it worked fine. Whatever the problem is it lies elsewhere. Are you sure the elements are empty? Try inspecting them via the dev tools. There's clearly some CSS going on in the picture that you haven't included. If you need further help please provide a [complete example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
 <div v-for="Rank in info">

 <p>{{ Rank }}</p>
```

Here Rank is an object, if you mean to use the rank key you need to

```
<p>{{ Rank.rank }}</p>
```

Answer (score 0):

[image: Code]
This is what you api gives. I think, because of a demo version.
There are no items to display. So Vue not displays anything. It's a problem with the server, not your code.
I'm worried, but maybe you need another api :(

Comment: please see my initial post. I get the whole Premier League als league table as response from the API (the premier league is free in demo).

Comment: I have an array with 20 objects

Comment: Can you add `league_id`"?